# How to lift state properly so that I can pass my prop between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a simple flashcard app that posts information about the flashcard to the backend whenever the user clicks on their answer choice. It posts the question, the answer choices, a unique id for each flashcard, the answer that was selected, and the correct answer. The next thing I want to send to the backend is the user's name that they enter into a form at the top of the page. The problem that I'm running into is that the function that posts the data to the backend is inside my flashcard.js which structures each flash card so I can't put the form on that file because then it is on every flashcard displayed but I just want the form displayed at the top.
Here is what my flashcard.js file looks like, the data is posted in the checkGuess function:

```
export default function Flashcard({ flashcard }) {     // recieving flashcard prop from our 
mapping in flashcardlist.js, each w a unique id

const MAX_TRIES = 4
// const [incorrect, setIncorrect] = useState(incorrect)
const [guess, setGuess] = useState(0)
const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false)
const [height, setHeight] = useState('initial') //sets the state for our initial height to be 
replaced by the max height

const frontEl = useRef() // lets us have a reference from the front and back through every 
rerendering of them
const backEl = useRef()

// const callDouble = () =>{
 //   checkGuess();
  //  postData();
 // } 


async function postData() {

    
}



const checkGuess = (answer, stateValue) => {
    try {
        console.log(stateValue)
        let result = fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',

            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                key: `${Date.now()}`,
                question: flashcard.question,
                answer: flashcard.answer,
                options: flashcard.options,
                guess: answer,
                user: stateValue
            })
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    if (answer === flashcard.answer) {
        setFlip(true)
        return
    }
    if (guess + 1 === MAX_TRIES) {
        setFlip(true)
    }

    setGuess(guess + 1)
    // setIncorrect(true)
}

function setMaxHeight() {
    const frontHeight = frontEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height //gives us dimensions of 
the rectangle but we only need the height
    const backHeight = backEl.current.getBoundingClientRect().height
    setHeight(Math.max(frontHeight, backHeight, 100)) // sets the height (setHeight) to the 
maximum height of front or back but the minimum is 100px
}

useEffect(setMaxHeight, [flashcard.question, flashcard.answer, flashcard.options]) //anytime any 
of these change then the setMaxHeight will change
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', setMaxHeight) //everytime we resize our browser, it sets 
the max height again
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', setMaxHeight) //removes the eventlistener 
when component destroys itself
  }, [])


return (
<div 
    onClick={() => postData()}
    className={`card ${flip ? 'flip' : ''}`} // if flip is true classname will be card and flip, 
  if flip isnt true it will just be card
    style={{ height: height }} //setting height to the variable height
    
    // onClick={() => setFlip(!flip)} // click changes it from flip to non flip
>
    <div className="front" ref={frontEl}>
        {flashcard.question}
        <div className='flashcard-options'>
            {flashcard.options.map(option => {
                return <div key={option} onClick={() => checkGuess(option)} className='flashcard- 
option'>{option}</div>
            })}
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div onClick={() => setFlip(!flip)} className='back' ref={backEl}>
        {flashcard.answer}        
    </div>
    
 </div>
)
}
// setting the front to show the question and the answers by looping through the options to make 
them each an option with a class name to style
// back shows the answer
```

so i've decided to render my form inside my flashcardList.js file because that is where all the cards from flashcard.js get sent and then displayed on the page in a grid like format. the form which is inside NameForm.js is rendered before the flashcards so that it appears above the flashcards. here is the flashcardlist.js file, it's very simple:

```
import React from 'react'
import Flashcard from './Flashcard'

export default function FLashcardList({ flashcards }) {
// taking in the flashcards as destructured props so we dont have to make a props. variable
return (

// card-grid is a container so we can put all the cards in a grid to ensure they change in size 
proportionally to the size of the window //
<div className='card-grid'> 

  {flashcards.map(flashcard => { // loops through the flashcards api and maps each one to 
flashcard

      return <Flashcard flashcard={flashcard} key={flashcard.id} /> // each flashcard is then 
passed down to the "Flashcard.js" component we created returned w a unique id
  })}
</div>
 )
}
```

and then here is my nameform.js file which creates the form, provides an alert to the browser displaying the name that was entered and setting the state:

```
import React from "react"


export default class NameForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {value: ''};   
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {  
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    this.props.checkGuess(this.props.answer, this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
}
checkGuess() {

}

render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
  );
}
}
```

The form works and the alert works displaying the correct name but when i try to console log stateValue inside the checkGuess function inside flashcard.js, it returns 'undefined' in the console so I'm clearly not lifting the state correctly because the alert to the browser displays the correct name that was inserted but the console log inside the flashcard.js function is undefined. does anybody know how to solve this? id really appreciate any help. let me know if you need any other information, my backend is just one simple python file that receives the data from the post request and sends it to the database. that works fine with the old data i just need to add the user id to this data.

Comment: @aneesh can you help with this?